# I'm trying to make a plugin that can check two categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin that can check two categories in Wordpress.

I want to have shortcode on pages like this:

`[cat_count_multi category="jp-events+jp-1月"]`

```
Plugin Name: Count Posts
Plugin URI: http://a4jp.com/plugins/
Description: Adds a custom short code that returns the number of posts.
Version: 1.0 altered
License: GPLv2 

*/



    function cat_count_multi( $atts ) {
    
function my_post_count($tax, $cat1, $cat2) {
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat1 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat2 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $query->post_count;
}
echo my_post_count('translates_category', 220, 238);
}

add_shortcode( 'cat_count_multi', 'cat_count_multi' );
```

What do I need to do to fix this so it works? I think it is very close.
I don't want to add the number of the pages but get the

`<?php echo ($wp_query->found_posts) ?>`

result.

Comment: What is the point of wrapping a function into a function here? That seems completely pointless, you might as well execute the same code directly (minus the `return`.)

Comment: And what is the actual _question_ here? If the `jp-events+jp-1月` value you are passing is supposed to be two category names/slugs separated by `+`- well then separated them first ...?

Comment: CBroe, I haven't made a plugin like this before so I'm not sure how to do it yet. I want to get the number of post that are in both categories, not the total number of each and add them. The function should count the number of posts that are in the category X(jp-events) and also in category Y(jp-1月). Less than the total number of posts in both X and Y. I can just use <?php echo ($wp_query->found_posts) ?> on templates to do this but need to make shortcode to count some posts.

Comment: I'm using 
function cat_count( $atts ) {
 $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
      'category' => null,
   'type' => null
 ), $atts );

    // get the category by slug.
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');
 $tpt = $atts['type'];
 
 return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
add_shortcode( 'cat_count', 'cat_count' ); for single categories now and it works.

Comment: If you want the count for each category separately, then you need to start by making two separate queries.

Comment: I want them joint. Not separate. For example, X,Y; X,Z; W,Y. X,Y=1; X=2; Y=2. I want the X,Y total.

Comment: Okay, so what other than what I mentioned in my second comment, is still the problem then?